# Image movement calibration

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, cross-correlation

I have a series of mostly identical images taken over a period of time. However, the objects in the images drifts over time, and I would like to correct for this. What is a good was to do this?

[EDIT] Okay, I may have to explain why I'm going this. I've taken some series of X-ray images of objects at different X-ray energies. I now want to compare the object are the various energies, but since it drifts I have to correct for the drift first. The object has no sharps edges or anything which otherwise would be easy to use for alignment. Therefore I'm looking for a more general method

Comment: Use only the most identical repeatedly?

Comment: I have posted en explanation in the original question

Comment: @Markus: here are some examples you might find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062826/houghlines-in-matlab/2079916#2079916, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477646/how-to-measure-the-rotation-of-a-image-in-matlab/7557783#7557783

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its general form this problem is known as [image registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration), and is a large topic of research in the image processing community. There are a varity of different methods and algorithms, often specialized for image modality. Depending on your images, to do this could be easy, or it could be difficult. I would recommend using one of the registration methods found in the file-exchange.

Based on your description of your images, it seems a [rigid transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation) should be enough. In that case, [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19086-automatic-2d-rigid-body-image-registration) method should work nicely.

Comment: I think this was the answer I was looking for! Thank you very much. I will take a closer look at the articles and scripts later today or tomorrow

Comment: For non-rigid transformations, try: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dr/software/index.html

Comment: @Markus: If you found an answer useful, please consider accepting it.