# How to know rotation degree in matlab for a rotated image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave

I would like to :

- step 1) Rotate an image with 20 degrees using this code `rotatedImage = imrotate(originalImage, 20);`.
- step 2) calculate degree rotation used in step 1 based only on the rotated image if it possible or based on rotated image and the original image.

there is any function in matlab could do the step 2 or a proposition to do that?

Comment: Here are a few examples I posted in the past, some of them for specific cases (by detecting corners, lines, edges, etc.. as features in both images, and using those to recover the transformation): http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557783, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2079916, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6563768, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16478211

Comment: Matlab has some built-in features for that. See the "find image rotation" web page -  http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale.html - and using a feature matching algorithm - http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html

Answer (score 5):

This example shows one way to perform step 2:

```
A = 'peppers.jpg';
img = im2double(imread(A));
img_r=imrotate(img,20,'nearest','crop');   % <-- this is the distorted image
                                           %     rotated 20 deg

xopt = fminsearch(@(x) imr(x,img_r,img), 10);  % <-- start with 10 deg as guess
```

where `imr` is the function

```
function obj= imr(x,img1,img2);
img1_r = imrotate(img1,x,'nearest','crop');
obj = sum((img2(:)-img1_r(:)).^2);
```

The function wraps `imrotate`, generating an objective function to minimize so that it can be used by `fminsearch`.

This shows the original, distorted, and reversed image (with angle determined as above):

[image]

Note the limitations: the rotated images are cropped so that a point-by-point comparison is possible during computation of the objective function. 
This is probably not the absolutely best way to do this, as I imagine that there are morphological algorithms designed to answer your specific question in a more general way. Still it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3000-fourier-mellin-based-image-registration-with-gui). I had used Fourier-Mellin transform to retrieve rotation. Its accurate up to 1 degree. I think you will have to invest some time + don't forget to check some papers on Fourier-Mellin transform