# How to estimate affine transformation matrix of a rotated image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I need to find  out rotation angle and translation value using given images (Original and Transformed).

**Original Image**

[image: Original Image]

**Transformed Image**

[image: Transformed Image]

**The Centroids for Original Image**

[image: The Centroids for Original Image]

**The Centroids for Transformed Image**

[image]

After finding the centroids I have tried to determine rotation angle using the centroid points' coordinates. For example in the first image chimney's coordinates are `(256,84)` in the original image and `(284,81)` in the transformed image.

I have made a calculation like

```
angle = atan(abs(284-256)/abs(81-84))/pi*180;
```

But I have found different angles for different points.

I want to know how to determine rotation angle and translation value of the transformed image.

Comment: Your missing the correct centre of rotation, but in any case this is a possible duplicate of [How to know rotation degree in matlab for a rotated image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703995/how-to-know-rotation-degree-in-matlab-for-a-rotated-image) With MATLAB, try using [`fitgeotrans`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html).

Comment: It's actually a simple application of SVD. There are some details [here](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671) and python and matlab code are at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks @Raab70. I have already read it